# How to update python3.10.4 to python3.10.7 in linux mint 21?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, linux-mint, cinnamon

I recently installed Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon 5.4.12. By default, Python v3.10.4 was installed, but the latest version of Python is v3.10.7. So now I want to update it, but I really don't know how to do that. So if someone helps me, I would be so pleased.

Comment: Unless your distro creates a package for 3.10.7, the only option is to build from source. There are many, many tutorials out there that explain how to do just that.

Comment: I recommend looking at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.